Is there an easy way to understand how to manipulate summations?
I'm working in a very very long calculation that could be done by hand but it might be tedious. Moreover, when doing by hand that amount of calculations I'm subject to errors, of course. Then I decided to use Mathematica to help me. I am using for some years but just copy pasting blocks of codes found on internet and building up a kind of a Frankenstein notebook to help me. I'm trying to be more professional and make my notebooks more clean, easy to follow and, moreover, simple to use.
My problem is to implement this process, given that

I want to implement a code which will help me to find that

I could do that, but kind of "manually": I calculated the derivatives by hand, I wrote it down on Mathematica this derivatives and then asked Mathematica to help me verify the expressions I found using Simplify or "==". But this is kind of not trustworthy since it relies on my own calculations for several steps. Moreover, this technic cannot be generalized in the future.
When I tried to implement it comes the trouble of dealing with summations. When doing it by hand it is obvious that I'll need to reindex some of this sums, moreover, sometimes I''ll need to split this sums into two parts in order to find what I want, for instance,

Here I was trying to find a way to do that and got stuck for some weeks. I'm even wondering if it is really possible or not...
I'll appreciate all of your help here!

I don't know whether it helps in your case, but I often make the summation "implicit", basically remembering that the expression needs to be summed over the index variable.  I can easily swap between implicit and explicit (using Sum) representations using substitution rules.  Obviously, you need to be careful that the manipulations you apply to the implicit form are valid.
